# Impresión de Información en Select2

Tags: php, javascript

tengo un pequeño problema, cuando intento imprimir la informacion que recibo por medio de ajax en un select con el plugin select2 no se marca la opcion que deberia, pero cuando le quito el plugin al select si se marca la opcion, alguna ayuda por favor. Estoy trabajando con PHP(codeigniter)

**Este es mi Ajax con la información que imprimo en los inputs y en el select que mencioné arriba**

```
success: function (data) {
            
            console.log(data)
            if (data.respuesta == 'success') {
                
            
$('#editarIdOtServicioTecnico').val(data.post.ID_OTServicioTecnico);


//SELECT2

$('#editarTipoDocumento').val(data.post.ID_Documento);
                        $('#editarTipoDocumento').html(data.post.Nombre_Documento);
                        $('#editarSerieDocumento').val(data.post.Serie_OTServicioTecnico);
                        $('#editarNumeroDocumento').val(data.post.NumeroDocumento_OTServicioTecnico);
                        $('#editarCliente').val(data.post.ID_Cliente)
                        $('#modalEditarOtServicioTecnico').modal('show');
                        
                    }
                }
    
    **Esta es mi vista**
    
        <select id="editarCliente"
                                        name="editarCliente"
                                        class="form-control select-search"
                                        data-placeholder="Seleccione un cliente"
                                        data-fouc
                                        required>
                                    <?php foreach ($cliente as $value): ?>
                                        
                                        <option value="<?= $value->ID_Cliente ?>"><?= $value->Nombre_Cliente . ' ' . $value->Apellido_Cliente ?></option>'
                                    
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido que funcione agregando al select un trigger change como en el siguiente código

```
$('#editarTipoDocumento').val(data.post.ID_Documento).trigger('change');
```